# Can I transfer a PS4 save file to PC?

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to copy a PS4 Fallout 4 save file to a PC and use it with the PC version?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, there is no tool available to the general public that converts Fallout 4's PS4 saves to PC saves.